# Limit FlipTileData to only two tile sizes c# WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, live-tile

So ive been toying around with the FlipTileData for awile and in my recent app i needed the tile to be only two sizes (not the biggest one). Ive tried my best so far with it, the code:

```
FlipTileData tileData = new FlipTileData
{
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:" + filename, UriKind.Absolute),
};
```

Ive looked up on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.shell.fliptiledata(v=vs.105).aspx for anymethods/properties that might relate to it but with no luck.

Ive seen apps on the store that have done this, but dont know if they are using the FlipTileData or something else.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You should go to the WMAppManifest.xml file in your project, under Properties.

Then you go to Application UI tab, which is the first.
One of the last options is `Support for Large Tiles`. You should uncheck that.

See image below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but i think i got it, I was using ShellTile.create to make the secondary tile (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207919(v=vs.105).aspx), didnt notice that there was a boolean paramter to prevent a wide tile.

Comment: @RaajitSharma You can answer your own question. Please do so so others can benefit.